# Preencher Map sem duplicar registros

Tags: java, expressões-lambda, map

Eu possuo um `List` de um objeto `A`. Nesse objeto,tenho 2 atributos: `Long` e um `BigDecimal`.

Como eu posso criar um `Map` onde a key vai ser o `Long` e o value vai ser o `BigDecimal`, utilizando uma  `lambda`?

O problema é que o `Long` não pode repetir.

Comment: Me fugiu agora o nome, mas se não me engano existe collection que não permite repetição dentro da mesma. Nesse link tem alguém que conseguiu algo parecido com o que você quer (está em inglês) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476548/which-data-structure-to-use-for-keeping-a-list-unique-with-insertion-order-intac

Comment: como você tem 2 tipos diferentes dentro de uma mesma lista?

Comment: Essa lista tem exatamente dois itens? Ou ela tem `Long`s e `BigDecimal`s alternados?

Comment: Pessoal, desculpe na pergunta...na verdade a Lista é de um Objeto e este tem 2 atributos: Long e BigDecimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos supor que a sua classe `A` tenha um método `getX()` que dá o valor `Long` e um método `getY()` que dá o `BigDecimal`. Com isso, você pode usar o [método `Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)):

```
List<A> suaLista = ...;
Map<Long, BigDecimal> map = suaLista.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getX, A::getY);
```

Vale frisar este detalhe da documentação do método:

> If the mapped keys contain duplicates (according to `Object.equals(Object)`), an `IllegalStateException` is thrown when the collection operation is performed.

Traduzindo:

> Se as chaves mapaeadas contiverem duplicatas (de acordo com o `Object.equals(Object)`), uma `IllegalStateException` é lançada quando a operação de coleção for realizada.

O que significa que essa exceção será lançada se a sua lista tiver pelo menos dois objetos com os mesmos `Long`s.

Se você quiser aceitar as duplicatas, e ficar com apenas uma delas, essa mesma documentação diz o seguinte:

> If the mapped keys might have duplicates, use `toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator)` instead.

Traduzindo:

> Se as chaves mapeadas puderem ter duplicatas, use `toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator)` ao invés disso.

E para manter só a primeira chave, seria então isso:

```
List<A> suaLista = ...;
Map<Long, BigDecimal> map = suaLista.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getX, A::getY, (p, q) -> p);
```

Esse `(p, q) -> p` é o `BinaryOperator` que recebe dois valores e devolve o primeiro.

Comment: @Douglas Há chaves duplicadas na lista passada? Se sim, como é que você gostaria que elas fossem resolvidas?

Comment: Pegaria a primeira ocorrência e pularia pra seguinte.

Comment: @Douglas Resposta editada.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar da biblioteca `Collectors`, o método `toMap()`.

Nesse exemplo, tenho um objeto com dois campos, `chave` e `valor`, que vão ser as respectivas chave / valor do `map`.

Também é possível tratar as chaves duplicadas utilizando uma *`função de merge`*, que é o terceiro parâmetro do `toMap()`

Nesse cenário, ele vai ter preferência em manter o valor antigo.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Q319074 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        Numero n1 = new Numero(Long.valueOf(1), new BigDecimal(10));
        Numero n2 = new Numero(Long.valueOf(1), new BigDecimal(20));
        Numero n3 = new Numero(Long.valueOf(3), new BigDecimal(30));

        Map<Long, BigDecimal> valores = Arrays.asList(n1, n2, n3)
                                        .stream()                                        
                                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Numero::getChave,
                                                              Numero::getValor,
                                                              (valorAntigo, valorNovo) -> valorAntigo));

       System.out.println(valores);
   }
}

class Numero {

    private Long chave;
    private BigDecimal valor;

    Numero(Long chave, BigDecimal valor) {
        this.chave = chave;
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public Long getChave() {
        return chave;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValor() {
        return valor;
    }
}
```